# Why doesn't Map have a map method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In order to "map" a Map object you have to destructure it to an array of arrays first. This seems backwards to me.

Can someone explain to me what the design rationale is behind this? I understand that other languages like Scala do have map methods for Maps, so I'm trying to understand why they are not available in Javascript.

This syntax seems so needlessly complex and verbose:

```
let mappedMap = new Map( 
  [...originalMap]
  .map(([k, v]) => [k * 2, '_' + v])
);
```

Couldn't it be something like this?

```
let mappedMap = originalMap.map((k, v) => [k * 2, '_' + v]);
```

Comment: You should ask this question at a venue frequented by the committee. Most outsiders don't have insight into their decisions.

Comment: It at least should be `let mappedMap = new Map(Array.from(originalMap, ([k, v]) => [k * 2, '_' + v])))` to avoid an extra copy of the array. It's also trivial to make an iterable version. I'd assume the answer is "because it can always be added later and is trivial to implement in a separate module". Plus a general `Iterable.map` would be more useful and that's also missing.

Comment: Afaik the problem was to be solved with generic methods on iterators, not on the `Map`s themselves. And iirc, there just was not much time or consensus or any proposal on how exactly to do these at the time the ES6 spec got finished, so it was left out. They're easy to polyfill, we expect userland libaries to jump in. As soon as usage patterns emerge, a standardisation will be considered. Just the same process as for the `Array` iteration methods.

Comment: If you are looking for something with this functionality, try Immutable Map (see https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was planning on giving Immutable.js a closer look since it makes sense for the kind of apps I program.

Answer (score 0):

Map on ES6 is currently represented as an iterable with a key/value system. And the array map function returns a new array. Im not sure if it would be possible to return a new version that way. I would use forEach for Maps and build new ones from there. If anything if you can build a function with the same functionality and I also definitely recommend looking into immutable.js